# Struggling to pass a single document through Firestore - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my customer class:

```
class Customer {
    // Creating a customer
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let contactNo: String
    let email: String
   
    init(name: String,surname: String,contactNo: String,email: String) {
        
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.contactNo = contactNo
        self.email = email
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using which keeps returning a nil:

```
class ProfileCus: UIViewController {
    // Labels to display data
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var surnameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactLabel: UILabel!
    
    // Reference to customer collection in Firestore
    private var  customerRefCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("customers")
    
    // Customer Object
    private var customer =  Customer(name: "a",surname: "a",contactNo: "a",email: "a")
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
         getDataFromFirebase{
               self.customerRefCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("customers")
                
               print(self.customer,"debug step 5")
               self.nameLabel.text = self.customer.name
               self.surnameLabel.text = self.customer.surname
               self.emailLabel.text = self.customer.email
               self.contactLabel.text = self.customer.contactNo
           }
    }
    
    func getDataFromFirebase(completion:@escaping() -> ()){
                    print(self.customer,"debug step 1")
                    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                    print(userID,"debug step 2")
                // Locate the user information on Firestore
                    customerRefCollection.document(userID!).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let err = error {
                        debugPrint("Error fetching documents: \(err)")
                    }
                    else {
                        // Ensure that if there's nothing in the document that the function returns
                    guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                    print(snap, "debug step 3")
                    // Parse the data to the customer model
                    let data = snap.data()
                    
                    let name = data?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let surname = data?["surname"] as?  String ?? ""
                    let email = data?["email"] as? String ?? ""
                    let contact = data?["contact no"] as? String ?? ""
                    // Create the customer and pass it to the global variable
                    let cus = Customer(name: name, surname: surname, contactNo: contact, email: email)
                    print(self.customer,"debug step 4")
                    self.customer = cus
                }
                    completion()
            }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong because the snapshot does return but the way I parse the data is wrong because the customer object returns a nil.

I have added print statements with tags saying debug step 1 ect so you can follow what happens at run time, here is the output:

020-08-13 21:15:20.388052+0200 Clean Wheels[8599:430648] 6.29.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
Customer(name: "a", surname: "a", contactNo: "a", email: "a") debug step 1
Optional("RWVTDIUuL1eahOLpZT1UmMl0cja2") debug step 2
<FIRDocumentSnapshot: 0x6000017499f0> debug step 3
Customer(name: "a", surname: "a", contactNo: "a", email: "a") debug step 4
Customer(name: "", surname: "", contactNo: "", email: "") debug step 5

It seems to me as if the data function is not the correct function to use because when I hard code the values its shows up in the UI Profile View, is there perhaps an alternative?

[Output once the code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejoSz.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document you're trying to get, and the values of the variables you're using with the query.  You could be doing something wrong with the query, but we just can't see what that is.  I suggest also adding some debug logging so we can see how the code executes.  What you have right now is impossible to follow without details.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have done so. Please note that I have added some print statements with debug steps to help show what is happening. I hope we can solve this, it seems as if the data function I use keeps returning nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this but what I'd suggest is passing the customer object through the completion handler (to the caller). You could also configure the customer object to take the document snapshot in its initializer (instead of taking 4 separate properties) and either return a customer object or `nil` (this would require a failable intializer which is incredibly basic). Also, I didn't see a need to declare so many instance properties (in this example, anyway) so I took them out. I also made the customer number an integer, not a string (to illustrate how I would structure the data).

```
class Customer {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let contactNo: Int // change this back to a string
    let email: String
   
    init(name: String, surname: String, contactNo: Int, email: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.contactNo = contactNo
        self.email = email
    }
}

class ProfileCus: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var surnameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getCustomer { (customer) in
            if let customer = customer {
                print(customer)
            } else {
                print("customer not found")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getCustomer(completion: @escaping (_ customer: Customer?) -> Void) {
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        Firestore.firestore().collection("customers").document(userID).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            if let doc = snapshot,
                let name = doc.get("name") as? String,
                let surname = doc.get("surname") as? String,
                let contact = doc.get("contact") as? Int, // cast this as a string
                let email = doc.get("email") as? String {
                let customer = Customer(name: name, surname: surname, contactNo: contact, email: email)
                completion(customer)
            } else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this. It says "customer not found" when I run the code. I printed the snapshot after the getDocument function call and it does contain the document however the parsing doesn't happen. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check your database and make sure all of the fields are in the document, the spelling matches, and they are the correct types (i.e. strings).

Comment: Nevermind, I found the spelling mistake. Everything works, I could not be more grateful. Thank you once again!

Comment: One last thing, the data takes about a second to load into the label and its noticeable in the view. Is it possible for me to add something to let the data display as the view loads up? You don't need to show me how but please put me on the right path?

Comment: It depends on your taste. You could populate all of the labels with values in `viewDidLoad` before you make the `getCustomer` call. `nameLabel.text = "Loading"`, for example. But this isn't the most attractive solution. You could add a loading spinner on the screen while the database is fetching your data (look up activity indicators, iOS has one ready for use). There is no magic here, really. Whatever you want the screen to look like before the data arrives, format it that way before you make the call to get the document.

Comment: Whatever you decide to do to let the user know the UI is in a loading state, I would highly recommend being consistent throughout the app. If you use a loading spinner here, use it elsewhere. Take a look at this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-uiactivityindicatorview-to-show-a-spinner-when-work-is-happening